# for loop in a scoreboard won't work properly

Tags: python

I want to create a scoreboard wherein if you search for a player, it displays that player's results for each level.

However, I can't get the `for` loop to work properly.

I know that the print statements at the bottom are a bit weird but it's the way it is required to be displayed

```
level_1_score = 0
level_2_score = 0
level_3_score = 0
level_4_score = 0
level_5_score = 0
player_search = input("Please enter the name of the "
                      "player you would like to search for.")    

no_of_lines = player_list.readlines()
length_of_file = len(no_of_lines)

for i in range(0, length_of_file):
    for line in player_list:

        player_name,level,score = line.split(",")
        player_list.readline()
        if player_search == player and level == 1:
            level_1_score = score

        elif player_search == player and level == 2:
            level_2_score = score

        elif player_search == player and level == 3:
            level_3_score = score

        elif player_search == player and level == 4:
            level_4_score = score

        elif player_search == player and level == 5:
            level_5_score = score

print("the scores for" , player_search, "are:") 
print("  Game level          Score")
print("_" * 30)
print("    Level 1            ",level_1_score,"\n")
print("    Level 2            ",level_2_score,"\n")
print("    Level 3            ",level_3_score,"\n")
print("    Level 4            ",level_4_score,"\n")
print("    Level 5            ",level_5_score,"\n")
```

Comment: Do you mean to iterate over every line as many times as there are lines? Meaning, your code would iterate over a 100 line file 100 times, for a total of 10,000 lines.

Answer (score 3):

If `player_list` is a file object you have exhausted the iterator with `.readlines()` so there is nothing to loop over with   `for line in player_list:` ,  you need to `seek` if you want the use readline or iterate over the lines with  `for line in player_list`:

```
for i in range(0,length_of_file):
    player_list.seek(0) # reset pointer
    for line in player_list:
```

I am not sure what `player_list.readline()`  is doing as you don't use the value returned so you may just want to remove it, you are already getting the lines with `for line in player_list`, it might make more sense just to iterate over `no_of_lines` which is a list of all lines:

```
for i in range(0,length_of_file):
    for line in no_of_lines:
```

Using `for i in range(0,length_of_file):` means you loop over the same lines `length_of_file` times, you are not using `i` so maybe just forget the outer loop and loop over the file object, forgetting  `no_of_lines` which will mean you loop over all the lines in the file once:

```
 for line in player_list:
    player_name,level,score = line.split(",")
    if player_search == player and level == 1:
        level_1_score = score
```

You are also comparing a string to an int with `and level == 1:...` so use a string instead for all your comparisons `and level == "1"`:...

All your code could be rewritten as:

```
level_1_score = 0
level_2_score = 0
level_3_score = 0
level_4_score = 0
level_5_score = 0
player_search = input("please enter the name of the player you would like to search for")

# open file, with will automatically close it for you
with open("your_file") as f:
    # loop over every line
    for line in f:
        player, level, score = line.split(",")
        if player_search == player and level == "1":
            level_1_score = score
        elif player_search == player and level == "2":
            level_2_score = score
        elif player_search == player and level == "3":
            level_3_score = score
        elif player_search == player and level == "4":
            level_4_score = score
        elif player_search == player and level == "5":
            level_5_score = score

print("the scores for" ,player_search,"are:") 
print("  Game level          Score")
print("_"* 30)
print("    Level 1            ",level_1_score,"\n")
print("    Level 2            ",level_2_score,"\n")
print("    Level 3            ",level_3_score,"\n")
print("    Level 4            ",level_4_score,"\n")
print("    Level 5            ",level_5_score,"\n")
```

Or using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to read the file and unpacking:

```
import csv
with open("your_file") as f:
    # csv.reader will split your data for you 
    r = csv.reader(f)
    # unpack elements each row
    for player, level, score in r:
        if player_search == player and level == "1":
            level_1_score = score
        elif player_search == player and level == "2":
            level_2_score = score
        elif player_search == player and level == "3":
            level_3_score = score
        elif player_search == player and level == "4":
            level_4_score = score
        elif player_search == player and level == "5":
            level_5_score = score
```

One last change would be to use a dict to store the levels so we can remove all the elifs:

```
player_search = input("please enter the name of the player you would like to search for")
import csv
# store levels in a dict so we can avoid all the level logic checks
levels = {"1": "0", "2": "0", "3": "0", "4": "0", "5": "0"}
with open("your_file") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for player, level, score in r:
        if player_search == player: 
            # use level as key to update the value in the dict
            levels[level] = score
          # break # uncomment if there can only be one name == to player_search
```

Then use a for loop with range from 1-6, `range` is half open so we get 1,2,3,4,5 then use the each int cast to str to access the dict and get the value for each level, using [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to format the output:

```
print("The scores for  {} are:".format(player_search))
print("  Game level          Score")
print("_"* 30)
for i in range(1,6):
    print("    Level {}          {} ".format(i,levels[str(i)]))
```

even in your own code, rechecking `if player_search == player:` is redundant, if we have a match all we need check is the level:

```
with open("your_file") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for player, level, score in r:
        if player_search == player:
            level_1_score = score
            if level == "2":
                level_2_score = score
            elif level == "3":
                level_3_score = score
            elif level == "4":
                level_4_score = score
            else: # if there can only be five levels we can use else
                level_5_score = score
          # break # again uncomment if there can only be one name == to player_search
```

Comment: @I.pricedavies, no worries, if you just want to get all the lines in the file, use the last part of the answer.

Comment: This advice has been amazing! but the level scores aren't changing it still just shows they are all zero

Comment: did you use the code where the level is compared to a string not an int?

Comment: yes, it still wouldn't work, but the code you just posted did, so it's all good!